# Lilypond "\set associatedVoice" trouble with stanzas

Tags: lilypond

I'm transcribing a song in which two verses have slightly differing notes. I decided to use `\set associatedVoice` to achieve this. It partly works but I'm having trouble getting the final words of the second stanza to appear:

[image: lilypond]

The conclusion of the lyric of verse 2 should be "... and it slows and ends." I can't figure how why "and ends" isn't appearing. I'd appreciate any help. Here's the lilypond code of this MWE:

```
\version "2.19.12"
\language english

global = {
  \clef treble
  \key c \major
  \time 4/4
  \tempo 4=120
}

vocalNotes = \relative c' {
  \global
  c4 d e f | %1
  g a
  << {\voiceOne b16 c d e }
     \new Voice = "alternative" {\autoBeamOff \voiceTwo b4 } >>
  d4 | %2
  c1 | %3
}

textVerseOne = \lyricmode {
  \set stanza = #"1. "
  This is a text. | %1
  Here it goes ver -- y fast and | %2
  ends. | %3
}

textVerseTwo = \lyricmode {
  \set stanza = #"2. "
  A se -- cond text, | %1
  and it \set associatedVoice = "alternative" slows
  \set associatedVoice = "vocalMelody" and | %2
  ends. | %3
}

\score {
  <<
  \new Voice = "vocalMelody" {\autoBeamOff \vocalNotes }
  \new Lyrics \lyricsto "vocalMelody" \textVerseOne
  \new Lyrics \lyricsto "vocalMelody" \textVerseTwo
  >>
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the `\set associatedVoice = "vocalMelody"` is scheduled to happen when the next associated note is played and there is no next associated note in the `Voice = "alternative"` any more.  Maybe you are better off doing this as a melisma on `"vocalMelody"` here.

Comment: The case I'm trying to solve is more complicated than a melisma could address, unfortunately! I'm struggling to understand the situation here--why doesn't `\set associatedVoice =  "vocalMelody"` at the end of m2 just switch the text back over to the `vocalMelody` variable beginning at m3? -s

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why your idea doesn't work, but you can use `\skip` instead of `\set associatedVoice`. They syntax is a bit illogical - `\skip` must be followed by a note duration, but when you use `\lyricsto` the duration is ignored and it skips one note.

```
\version "2.18"
\language english

global = {
  \clef treble
  \key c \major
  \time 4/4
  \tempo 4=120
}

vocalNotes = \relative c' {
  \global
  c4 d e f | %1
  g a
  << {\voiceOne b16 c d e }
     \new Voice = "alternative" {\autoBeamOff \voiceTwo b4 } >>
  d4 | %2
  c1 | %3
}

textVerseOne = \lyricmode {
  \set stanza = #"1. "
  This is a text. | %1
  Here it goes ver -- y fast and | %2
  ends. | %3
}

textVerseTwo = \lyricmode {
  \set stanza = #"2. "
  A se -- cond text, | %1
  and it slows \skip16 \skip16 \skip16 and | %2
  ends. | %3
}

\score {
  <<
  \new Voice = "vocalMelody" {\autoBeamOff \vocalNotes }
  \new Lyrics \lyricsto "vocalMelody" \textVerseOne
  \new Lyrics \lyricsto "vocalMelody" \textVerseTwo
  >>
  }
```

If all else fails, you can use `\lyricmode` instead of `\lyricsto`, and append a duration to the syllables in the same way as for notes. You can then use `\associated voice` to get the syllables centred under the notes.

```
\version "2.18"
\language english

global = {
  \clef treble
  \key c \major
  \time 4/4
  \tempo 4=120
}

vocalNotes = \relative c' {
  \global
  c4 d e f | %1
  g a
  << {\voiceOne b16 c d e }
     \new Voice = "alternative" {\autoBeamOff \voiceTwo b4 } >>
  d4 | %2
  c1 | %3
}

textVerseOne = \lyricmode {
  \set stanza = #"1. "
  \set associatedVoice = "vocalMelody"
  This4 is a text. | %1
  Here it goes16 ver -- y fast and4 | %2
  ends.1 | %3
}

textVerseTwo = \lyricmode {
  \set stanza = #"2. "
  \set associatedVoice = "vocalMelody"
  A4 se -- cond text, | %1
  and it
  \set associatedVoice = "alternative" slows4
  \set associatedVoice = "vocalMelody" and | %2
  ends.1 | %3
}

\score {
  <<
  \new Voice = "vocalMelody" {\autoBeamOff \vocalNotes }
  \new Lyrics \textVerseOne
  \new Lyrics \textVerseTwo
  >>
  }
```

Comment: Yes, \skip can be useful, and I do use it at times. The situation I'm trying to solve here, though, is complex in ways not captured by my MWE, so I'm hoping to get to a solution that uses instantiation of a new voice to help make the resulting output clear to a reader.

Comment: Personally, I usually use `\lyricmode` with explicit syllable lengths. it's a bit more typing, but it always does what it says on the tin.

Comment: It took a little doing, but this solved my issue! Switching over to `\lyricmode` and adding all the syllable lengths did it -- now my `associatedVoice` construct works as I'd hoped. Thank you! If you want to write it up as an answer, I'll happily accept it.